# Change in module update function not saved

Tags: civicrm, webforms

I have a module that uses update function in the module.install file.

When debugging these changes during development, I call the function from `hook_init()`.

```
function mymodule_init() {
  require_once __DIR__ . '/mymodule.install';
  mymodule_update_7016();
```

Everything is just peachy. The update code is run, which makes changes to a the CiviCRM settings for a Drupal webform. When I load the webform edit page I can see the changes have been made.

Now I think I'm done with this, and I can just use `drush updb` to call my upgrader. I do so. My updater runs without errors.

However, when I check the page, there are no changes reflected in the webform. The exact same code is run from two different places, and in one case the results are saved; in the other, nothing happens.

I have tested making changes to the node title (which is unrelated to [webform_civicrm](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm)) and it works in both cases so the problem seems to be related to webform_civicrm.

Why would the behaviour be different in an upgrading function compared to when run as part of the request lifecycle in `hook_init()`? I've added `drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);` to my code to see if it made any difference, but it didn't.

Comment: How it's called shouldn't matter. It's the code contained in your update hook where the issue likely resides.